# Browsers not loading optimized image unless name change

Tags: html, css, image

So I am building a website and I have a few images that I ran through https://tinypng.com/ to reduce the size.

One of the images was this one:

http://postimg.org/image/jxxbx85xv/

Which is named map.png. The size of the that image is 508KB, which is a lot.

After optimized it went down to 113KB:

http://postimg.org/image/g6xya7csp/

Now the big problem is that if I just overwrite the map.png (508KB) with the new version of 113KB I get from firefox the following message:

Image corrupt or truncated: < path to image >

And it displays less than half of the image.

I get the similar thing in Chrome (did not test in IE).

Now what confuses me is if I change the image name to map2.png (and update the html to point to the new image) the image will display without any problems.

My question is: Is this a bug in how browsers cache images? Is there anything I can do besides changing the name of the image and the src of the img tag?

Thanks

UPDATE

Yes even after a hard update (CTRL+F5 many times) I still see this issue.

On my local machine I am using apache2. I tried restarting apache but that didn't solve anything.

**UPDATE2**

I have verified that if I upload the images to the live server the error does not appear. I only see this problem in my local server (apache2 on ubuntu). I still wish I had a way of fixing this but as long as it works on the live server I guess I can live with this.

Thanks for all the help guys.

***UPDATE3***

So I thought it was weird that the images displayed correctly on the live server and not on my local server.

So I googled it a bit and it seems that this has to due with how Apache sends static content.

So I added these to my .htaccess (which I will move to my virtual host conf file later):

```
EnableSendfile Off
EnableMMAP Off
```

Now the images display correctly.

**Apache documentation links**

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablesendfile

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablemmap

Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior with a hard-refresh?

Comment: Have you tried flushing your cache first, or simply refreshing via CTRL+F5? BTW best way to compress an image is by using Photoshop or GIMP, using progressive JPEG and quality ~ 80% (not this the issue though and it's more complicated than this)

Comment: wich server are you using?? apache?? usually apache has some directives depending on file types, and it caches them for some hours.

Answer (score 0):

An Easy solution to prevent caching and loading always a new image, is adding a non-fixed parameter at the end of the url:

`http://postimg.org/image/g6xya7csp/?3123423` <-- Numer is non fixed and generated everytime

if you run this non-fixed num query, the server will look for a different URL image, and will serve the updated one. It´s a little trick that helps to pass through the cached image and read the new again.

Anyway, Apache can configure different rules on each .htaccess (on each directory) with the mod_expires and you´ll be able to edit the expire time for each type of object:

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 second"
 # ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 day"
 # ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 day"
 # ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 day"
 # ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 8 hours"
 # ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 second"
 # ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 30 days"
 # ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 30 days"
</ifModule>
```

As you see, I´ve commented my Expires to make them not being cached. 
Hope you can solve your problem with those 2 tricks.

Here are the docs:

https://docs.joyent.com/guides/apache-guide/configuring-mime-types-in-htaccess
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html

Comment: I did try serving the image like < img src="/imgs/map.png?2323" > but that gave me the same result (firefox saying the image was corrupted or truncated). I will try the expire trick. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727219/image-corrupt-or-truncated-in-firefox

Comment: The images aren't that big. It goes from 500kb to around 100kb, and the dimensions are nowhere near the dimensions indicated in the bug.

Comment: but there they say about loading many images too fast in the stackoverflow question, could it be your problem? Is the same when typing just the image url on the browser?

Comment: This happens even if I go to the image directly, but if I change the name of the image it will load correctly.

Comment: maybe the file is really corrupted? did you tried to delete the file and copy it again in the server??

Comment: As I said in the Question if I do change the name the image is loaded without any problems so firefox saying that the image is corrupted is wrong and I am experiencing this locally (vagrant running ubuntu while I am on windows 7)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78156/discussion-between-alejandro-teixeira-munoz-and-antoniocs).